# Codeigniter How to set Task Scheduler Using Command Line?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using Codeigniter to setup Task Scheduler using following command:

`schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 2 /tn "cronmailwin" /tr "php C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php\cronEmail\index"`

In the above command i am trying to hit CI Controller. But it doesn't work. Please give me a suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: So cronEmail is the one you are trying to execute right?

Comment: codeigniter version is 2.1.2

Comment: Yes i am trying cronEmail to execute.

Comment: Do you know this CLI library? https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cli

Comment: Or this tutorial? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: run command with -f as:schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 2 /tn "cron" /tr "c:/xampp/php/php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php cronEmail index"

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax I am using in Task Scheduler as the arguments for the php.exe process:

```
"C:\ABSOLUTE\PATH\TO\FILE" CONTROLLER METHOD
```

So in your case:

```
 "C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php" cronEmail index
```

Including the spaces.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working.I am getting "File Not Found" error message.

Comment: Is that the correct path? Also do you have all the right permissions?

Comment: Yes path is correct.  I am getting following error -              ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'cronEmail'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.                                                                                                                                  I am using it like this                                                                 schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "cronmailwin" /tr "php D
:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php" cronEmail index

Comment: Following code is work for me  schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "cronmailwin" /tr "php D :\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php cronEmail index". But it will hit only cronEmail constructor not index method.

Comment: isn't the index method the main one in your controller that would be triggered first?

Comment: Yes it is main method

Comment: Shouldn't it run? what if you rename the method?

Comment: I am getting same issue please see it - http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/122685/#607942

Comment: A problem connecting to the db?

Answer (score 0):

run command with -f as:schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 2 /tn "cron" /tr "c:/xampp/php/php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\index.php cronEmail index"